# Error running grunt-responsive-images task

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm trying to set up grunt with grunt-responsive-images, and getting the following error:

`Warning: Could not execute GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick: gm "identify" "-ping" "-format" "%m:%T:%s" "assets/_img/bgAbout.jpg" this most likely means the gm/convert binaries can't be found`

The npm and ImageMagick are both installed, have also tried GraphicsMagick (with default engine) to no avail.

I've verified all my versions of node/grunt/packages and I'm on Windows 10 if that's helpful info.

relevant bits from gruntfile.js:

```
responsive_images: {
    dev: {
        options: {
            engine: 'im'
        },
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            src: ['**/*.{gif,jpg,png}'],
            cwd: 'assets/_img/',
            dest: 'assets/test/'
        }]
    }
},

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-responsive-images');

grunt.registerTask('default', ['responsive_images']);
```

All relevant help I've found points to ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick not being installed, but it is. What could be hindering the communication between the task and IM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugh. foiled by Windows UAC! Ran cmd as administrator, and it worked like a charm. Why did it take so long for my basic customer support troubleshooting reflexes of yore to kick in?